# How to create regular expression in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6

I currently have a regex that looks like:

`const ignoreRegex = new RegExp(/^\/(?!fonts|static).*$/)`

However, I also have a dynamic array of strings like `"test"` which need to be ignored too. I need to somehow map through this array and add each string to the regex, such that:

```
  const ignoreRegex = new RegExp(/^\/(?!fonts|static + ignoreRoutes.map(x => `|${x}`) + ).*$/)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You'll have to escape the string to create the regex correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the `/ /` surrounding your regular expression and use a string in the RegExp constructor.

See the code below.

```js
const ignoreFolders = ["fonts", "static"];
const ignoreRoutes = ["route1", "route2"];
const ignore = ignoreFolders.concat(ignoreRoutes);

const ignoreRegex = new RegExp(`^\/(?!${ignore.join("|")}).*$`);

console.log(ignoreRegex);
```

If you have any regex special characters in your string, they will be escaped automatically.

Comment: It seems to be adding a `\/` before each string in my dev environment. Maybe because of babel transpilation? Output looks like: `/^\/(?!\/fonts|\/static).*$/`

Comment: Probably you are trying to ignore ```/fonts``` rather than ```fonts```. In regular expression, ```/``` has a special meaning. So ```/``` has to be escaped using ```\/```.

Comment: If you don't want ```\/```, make sure to remove all ```/``` that appears before the strings in ```ignoreRoutes``` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ignoreRoutes = ["fonts","static","aaa","bbb","ccc"];
const ignoreRegex = new RegExp(`^\\/(?!${ignoreRoutes.join("|")}).*$`);
```

Comment: It seems to be adding a \/ before each string in my dev environment. Maybe because of babel transpilation? Output looks like: /^\/(?!\/fonts|\/static).*$/

Comment: try "+".
 new RegExp('^\\/(?!'+(ignoreRoutes.join("|"))+').*$');